# Active Directory Trust issue

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to setup an active directory trust between two domains. When I set up the trust from my domain it does not work.

All my servers are Server 2008 R2 with the domain functional level of 2008 R2.

Here are my steps:

1. start, administrative tools, active directory domains and trusts
2. Right click my domain and then properties
3. Click the trusts tab and then "New trust"
4. I type the name of the other domain and click next
5. Next it tells me "the name you specified is not a valid Windows domain name. Is the name a Kerberos V5 Realm and asks if it is a Realm trust or Trust with Windows domain.

Does anyone know whats going on? I have been googling all day and cant find the answer.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I've edited your question to be a little more sane. You don't make a trust between domain controllers, you make a trust between domains or forests. There is also no such thing as a "main" domain controller, they are multi-master peers. The PDC Emulator has a special role in external trusts, but that doesn't appear to matter much here. You also said that you have all 2008 servers with a DFL of 2008 R2 which is impossible. I assume you mean that your servers are all 2008 R2, so I've edited your question appropriately.

Comment: Also, you don't mention what kind of trust you are trying to make here. Is it a forest trust? An external trust? What is the DFL of the trusted domain? Are you trying to create the trust inbound or outbound or two-way?

Comment: Forest trust. I am trying to do a two way trust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be able to resolve the FQDN of the active directory that you wish to trust and also one or more domain controllers in that environment as well. This is typically done with either a DNS conditional forwarder that points to one or more of their DCs, or a stub zone.

If you do not have working name resolution between the two environments, you cannot create a trust.

Comment: MD, thank you very much.  I will give this a try right now and report back.

Comment: It works, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I have the same issue and my DNS on both domains seems spot on but I still get the error saying `the name you specified is not a valid Windows domain name`! - I can ping server1.domain1.com from server2 and ping server2.domain2.com from server1.  I can also ping domain1.com from server2 and ping domain2.com from server1 with no issues.  server2 seems to be able to add the trust to server1 just fine (does not receive the message).  server1 on the other hand gets the message saying domain2.com is not a valid domain.  Ideas?